# Angular 2 routing always go through root /

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

If I have this configuration for routes:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './private/private.module#PrivateModule' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

When I navigate to `/login` the lazy loaded private module will always load. The big problem is if I have `canLoad` guard there so that only authenticated users can access it. But then if every time I go to `/login` I go through the `canLoad` guard that will redirect back to `/login` that will go again through `canLoad` and so on - an infinite loop will be created. Any thoughts or workarounds on that.

Ideally I want to have a public route `/login` and a private module `/` which will contain private modules along with shared modules among them that will be loaded lazy. I don't want any prefix on the route that's why I want to use root route `/`.

```
|_ core
|_ shared
|_ login
|_ private
|____ shared
|____ core
|____ dashboard
|____ etc
```

**EDIT:**

To illustrate here is a screenshot:

[image]

When I go to login you can see `0.chunk.js` has been loaded which is the private module. It should not load when it is defined on `/` route and I am not on `/` route.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: How to avoid infinite loop if I include `canLoad` guard for the root route. Or in other words how to avoid going through the defined root route if I navigate to `/login`?

Comment: Check edit, please.

Comment: I'll take a look later

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `canActive` from login route and add `canLoad: [LoginGuard]` in '' route. As you loin route is a on route, it's not required to be guarded.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './private/private.module#PrivateModule', canLoad: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

Comment: `LoginGuard` protects authenticated users to go back to `/login` page. Also `canActivate` is not needed for lazy loaded modules. It should be `canLoad`.

Comment: In his case the login guard is sending to login page and then login page sending to login guard and going to infinite loop. So same thing can be handled in one guard

Comment: changed to canLoad now

Comment: Forget about the `LoginGuard`. It is not the problem. You don't know it's logic. Why do you move it? I will remove it from the question. I guess it is confusing you.

Comment: I think you are little confused! your loin page will be public and anyone without authentication can use it. So you dont need a guard there. So I am not talking about loginGuard (no guard for login). For the other routs add a guard and when the user is not authenticated redirect them to login page. In the login component check if the user object is available, then redirect that to the'' route.In auth guard always check if user object is available, so as the user object is available, the user is logged in and it will load the module and redirect to there.

Comment: Please check my question again. I am not asking about how to add guards and how to check authentication. I have also edited my answer with screenshot.